# How to get the name of the tag created (or modified) by a Mercurial changset?

Tags: mercurial, tags

I am working on an application which builds up a database of changesets from a Mercurial repository. Any new changesets are read at intervals by running **hg log** and parsing the output. We need to add tag information to changesets in our database as they are updated in the repository.

If someone tags a changeset by running:

```
hg tag -r 1 mytag
```

the first revision is the repository is tagged with **mytag** and a new changeset is created

If I now run:

```
hg log -v -l 1
```

to get the the details of latest changeset, the **summary** field shows "Added tag mytag for changeset b669d03aefa1". I can parse this and get the name of the tag and hash for the tagged changeset.

However if the changeset is tagged with a comment e.g.

```
hg tag -r 1 mytag -m "my comment"
```

the **summary** field in the **hg log** output is overwritten with "my comment" and there does not seem to be any way to find out which tag has been added by this changeset.

I have looked through the **hg log --template** variables, but there only seems to be variables relating to tags on the current changeset - not tags added or modified by the current changeset.

I started down the route of using **hg annotate .hgtags**. The output from this command maps each tag to the revision where is was created however the **.hgtags** file does not include tags added to remote repositories even after a pull and update.

Alternatively I could maintain a list of tags by regularly querying the output from **hg tags** and updating the changesets as these change, however I am hoping there would be more efficient (or simpler) method to get the tag name directly from the revision.

Comment: Create a tag for each changeset doesn't look right. Could you elaborate more about the reasons that lead you to do that? Why don't use the changesetid as the primary key?

Comment: I'm not creating tags for each changeset. Our application (a continous integration app) displays a table of changesets in the repository. I need to display any tags for each changeset row. 

We currently poll the repository every 30 seconds and retrieve the latest changesets using hg log. We only get the latest changesets for performance reasons as the repositories we need to support are very large.

Comment: Some of the changesets are for a tag. The tag may be on a previous changeset already in our database. I need to be able to get the name of the tag updated by the current changeset and the revision number of the changeset which has been tagged.

How this is stored in the database is not important, but we have one table for changesets with changesetid as a primary key and another table of changesettags with changesetid as a foreign key.

Comment: Using hg tags to retrieve the full list of tags each time we poll the repository and updating the full table of changesettags may end up being the only solution. I however am hoping to find a method to get the tag name directly from the revision as this would be more efficient and fit in with the workflow we are using for retrieving tags from other repository types that that we support such as Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hg tags` **is** the natural way for checking tags in the repo

`hg tags -v` will aloow you to differentiate also local and global tags

If you still want to use `hg log` variations, for fresh Mercurial you can

`hg log --template "{if(tags,'{rev} {tags}\n')}"`

output almost identical to `hg tags`, but can be limited to shortened list

Also, if new tags added **always** only for *more new changeset* than existing tags, you can use something like

`hg log -r tip --template "{latesttag}\n"`

and changed output will means "New tag appeared in repository"

**Final note**

You can (to some degree) detect, "who" and "when" created|edited tags. It will be more than single command + *some logic* on top of command, but (hg-git repository used to tests)

```
> hg tags
tip                              598:792955be68dd
0.4.0                            594:a3c3b8077cbe
0.3.4                            572:586b7aa96466
0.3.3                            473:9d44dafbb31c
0.3.2                            443:a9c0b93488d4
0.3.1                            436:556c3c586c4a
0.3.0                            433:fa3edeec7ed1
0.2.6                            377:46d390f404da
0.2.5                            364:bc72dd89c2c9
0.2.4                            358:b53421918a89
0.2.3                            348:5d39b98e5083
0.2.2                            322:a222399a59d7
0.2.1                            278:21ead8190d9c
0.2.0                            269:77d6c9eb02fb
0.1.0                            253:505d7cdca198

> hg log --template "{rev}: {author|person} {date|isodate}\n" .hgtags
595: Augie Fackler 2013-03-24 16:39 -0500
573: Augie Fackler 2012-11-01 09:11 -0500
474: Augie Fackler 2012-08-05 21:11 -0500
444: Augie Fackler 2012-01-27 11:52 -0600
437: Augie Fackler 2011-09-13 18:16 -0500
434: Augie Fackler 2011-09-09 16:17 -0500
378: Augie Fackler 2011-03-01 08:24 -0600
365: Augie Fackler 2010-11-02 08:37 -0500
359: Augie Fackler 2010-08-25 15:45 -0500
349: Augie Fackler 2010-07-05 11:56 -0500
323: Augie Fackler 2010-05-22 22:12 -0500
279: Augie Fackler 2009-12-26 13:46 -0600
270: Augie Fackler 2009-12-26 12:42 -0600
254: Augie Fackler 2009-10-17 20:12 -0400
```

For any (created locally or pulled from related repo) tag in changeset N authorship can be extracted from log for changeset N+1

Comment: Thanks for your input. Using hg tags may end up being the only solution. However as I said at the end of my question, I am hoping to find a method to get the tag name directly from the revision as this would be more efficient. It would also fit in with the workflow we are using for retrieving tags from other repository types that that we support such as Git.

Comment: @sparkplug - alternatives added to answer

Comment: The alternatives still don't solve my problem however it does seem that that is no failsafe way to get the name of the tag added by changeset either by hg log or otherwise. I can't assume that it is the latest tag. I am now using hg tags to retrieve the current tag list updating the database after comparing the current tag list with the stored list. In only issue now that there may be multiple changesets each time I call hg log so it's not possible to know which changeset created the tag and to know the actual time a tag was created and who created it. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, as it seems that there is no better solution

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I am indeed using the presence of .hgtags  to ascertain whether a given changeset is a tagging changeset. Note however that the tagging changeset will not necessarily be the tagged changeset plus one if the --rev option is used with hg tag.